# Trying to get the latest execution of a concurrent (oracle 11g)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to obtain the latest execution of a specific concurrent; i am connecting to an **Oracle 11g database**.

My query works just fine but for some reason i was not able to obtain only the latest execution, i mean the **request_id**

**This my query:**

```
select nam.user_concurrent_program_name program,
       con.request_id "request id",
       to_char(con.actual_start_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') start,
       to_char(con.actual_completion_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') end,
       trunc((con.actual_completion_date - con.actual_start_date) * 1440, 2) time_mm,
       con.status_code status,
       us.user_name user,
       con.oracle_process_id,
       con.oracle_session_id,
       con.argument_text
  from fnd_concurrent_programs_tl nam,
       fnd_concurrent_requests    con,
       fnd_user                   us
 where con.concurrent_program_id = nam.concurrent_program_id
   and con.requested_by = us.user_id
   and con.actual_start_date >= to_date('20/11/2019', 'dd/mm/rrrr')
   and con.actual_start_date < to_date('23/11/2019', 'dd/mm/rrrr') + 1
   and nam.user_concurrent_program_name like 'report concurrent sales'
   and co.request_id =
       (select max(con.request_id)
          from fnd_concurrent_requests can
         where con.request_id = can.request_id);
```

The problem is that i am getting several rows and i only want the latest row, with the highest request_id.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` analytic function with descending `request_id` (assuming `request_id` is a primary key column as being an identity, no **tie**(*repeated column values among rows*) will occur):

```
select program, "request id", "start", "end", "request id", time_mm, status, "user", 
       oracle_process_id, oracle_session_id, argument_text
  from
  (
    select nam.user_concurrent_program_name program,
           con.request_id "request id",
           to_char(con.actual_start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') "start",
           to_char(con.actual_completion_date,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') "end",
           trunc((con.actual_completion_date-con.actual_start_date)*1440,2) time_mm,
           con.status_code status,
           us.user_name "user",
           con.oracle_process_id,
           con.oracle_session_id,
           con.argument_text,
           row_number() over (order by con.request_id desc) as rn
      from fnd_concurrent_programs_tl nam
      join fnd_concurrent_requests con
        on con.concurrent_program_id=nam.concurrent_program_id
      join fnd_user us
        on con.requested_by = us.user_id
     where con.actual_start_date >= date'2019-11-20' 
       and con.actual_start_date <  date'2019-11-23' + 1
       and nam.user_concurrent_program_name like  'report concurrent sales'
  )  
where rn = 1
```

P.S. Pay attention for reserved keywords such as `user` and `end` which are wrapped up with quotes.

**Edit** ( *for the new case* ) **:** You can convert **the where** condition for the subquery to :

```
 where con.actual_start_date >= date'2019-11-20' 
   and con.actual_start_date <  date'2019-11-23' + 1
   and ( nam.user_concurrent_program_name in 
                                            ('report concurrent sales',
                                             'report concurrent customers',
                                             'report concurrent sunday') )
```

and add `partition by` clause if you want to have one row for each `user_concurrent_program_name` seperately as

```
row_number() 
over (partition by nam.user_concurrent_program_name order by con.request_id desc) as rn
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for replying!. Gonna check it out :)

Comment: Dude, it is working but if i want to add another line in order to obtain the latest execution of 2 or more concurrents it shows zero rows, i mean this:
and nam.user_concurrent_program_name like  'report concurrent sales'
and nam.user_concurrent_program_name like  'report concurrent customers'
and nam.user_concurrent_program_name like  'report concurrent sunday'

Do you get me?

Comment: @Student_new what do you have by getting rid of `where rn = 1` with your new current conditions added ..? Btw, I suppose you need an **OR** operator instead of **AND** between like statements,without forgetting to keep them within **parentheses**, or cleanly you can accumulate as `and nam.user_concurrent_program_name in ('report concurrent sales','report concurrent customers','report concurrent sunday')`.

Comment: If i delete the statement rn = 1 with my new conditions i got zero rows.
If i put the condition  rn = 1 using *and nam.user_concurrent_program_name in ('report concurrent sales','report concurrent customers','report concurrent sunday')* i only got 1 row :/

Comment: yes, because you need to catch every three condition at the same time. So you cannot use **AND** operator in this case @Student_new

Comment: Oh, sorry. What should i do then? Im pretty lost :(

Comment: Dude, I've tried but i am still getting only 1 row.. not 2 or 3

Comment: OK, I got now, you want to have them seperately @Student_new . Check the last edit out.

Comment: It is working now but i have a problem.: i do not fully understand what you did.
Why the first time it did not work? Why did you modify the "over" operator?

Comment: `partition by` resets the iteration for each group @Student_new

Comment: Dude, how are you? Can i ask you something: how would you do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59021859/best-way-to-receive-an-email-after-concurrent-failed-sql-trigger-applicatio ?

Comment: well, I replied you can check it out @Student_new

Comment: Thanks pal; the problem is that i would like to receive an email. How should i do that? I dont want to execute the query everytime to see if it failed or not. Do you get me?

Comment: Dude, how are you? Could you please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061291/passing-arguments-inside-procedure-message-not-working-oracle ?