# Best way to receive an email after concurrent failed (sql - trigger - application)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to receive an email if the concurrent execution endded up with an error;

Take a look: i have a query which contains the latest execution of a concurrent (i am using Oracle 11g):

```
select *
  from
  (
    select yer.user_murcurrent_program_yere program,
           mur.request_id "request id",
           mur.status_code status,
           row_number() over (partition by yer.user_murcurrent_program_yere order by mur.request_id desc ) as rn
      from fnd_murcurrent_programs_tl yer
      join fnd_murcurrent_requests mur
        on mur.murcurrent_program_id=yer.murcurrent_program_id
      join fnd_user us
        on mur.requested_by = us.user_id
     where mur.actual_start_date >= date'2019-11-20' 
       and mur.actual_start_date <  date'2019-11-23' + 1
       and (yer.user_murcurrent_program_yere like 'Report sales')   
   )                                         
where rn = 1;
```

This query returns something like this:

```
|   program  |request_id|status |
|Report sales|5878547894|WARNING|
```

In this case i would like to recieve an email saying:

> The concurrent "Report sales" with rquest_id '5878547894' endded with
>   status WARNING

**These are the possible status:**

> WARNING,ERROR, STAND BY, RUNNING, COMPLETE

**I only want to receive the email if the status is: WARNING, ERROR or STAND BY.**

How can i do that? What application should i do or create?. I need to do that and i'm pretty lost.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Check out Oracle's [UTL_SMTP package](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_smtp.htm)

Comment: Hey dude, thank you for replying. Is there exist another way to do that? Have you got any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double pipes(`||`) as concatenation operators, and filter the results out by your desired status types listed within parentheses after the `IN` operator for the query.

Create a procedure and take your query into it as a cursor and use [`utl_http`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_http.htm#ARPLS070) package within that procedure as below :

```
create or replace procedure pr_mail_me is

  v_email varchar2(100) := 'my.email@xmail.com';
  v_rep   varchar2(4000);
  v_url   varchar2(4000);

  cursor crs_request is
  select 'The concurrent '||program||' with request_id '||request_id||' ended with status '|| 
           status as message, request_id
    from
    (
       <the subquery>
      )
   where rn = 1
     and status in ('WARNING','ERROR','STAND BY');    

begin

  for c in crs_request
  loop
  begin

    v_url := 'http://www.mycompany.com/path_to/default.aspx?email=' ||
              v_email ||'&out_message='||c.message||'&out_request_id='||c.request_id;
    v_rep := utl_http.request(utl_url.escape(v_url,false,'UTF-8'));

   exception
       when others then
            v_url := 'http://www.mycompany.com/path_to/default.aspx?email=' ||
                      v_email ||'&out_message='||substr(sqlerrm,1,250)||'&out_request_id='||c.request_id;
                      v_rep := utl_http.request(utl_url.escape(v_url,false,'UTF-8'));
        end;
  end loop;
end;
```

in order to receive e-mails as calling this procedure.

Comment: Thank you for replying, dude. The problem is that i want to get notified everytime the concurrent fails; i want to receive an email. How should i do that?

Comment: Thanks buddy!. What should i put inside *v_url* variable?Where should i put the email addresses (1,2 or many others?)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by *"use utl_http package"*; i am pretty lost tbh :(

Comment: If i execute the query it asks me for values

Comment: my bad, forgot to add a sample e-mail address @Student_new .

Comment: Dude, how can i do to send the mail to multiple email addresses?. Why did you use *create or replace procedure*?

Comment: Dude, it is not working, it shows an error message, take a look: https://imgur.com/a/wHq8O8M .*Warning: compiled but with compilation errors* Why?

Comment: -Barbaros Özhan, this is the error:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored 48/13
PLS-00201 - identifier V_URL must be declared 48/13
PL/SQL: Statement ignored 50/64
PLS-00201 - identifier V_URL must be declared 50/64

Why?

Comment: Dude, i added this statement: v_url   varchar2(4000); but now it is showing another error: PLS-00302: component  must be declared..component request_id must be declared 43/5/component request_id must be declared 49/13. What should i do?

Comment: Didn't you add request_id column to the select statement of the cursor ? such as 
 `cursor crs_request is select request_id..` @Student_new , and then `c.request_id` within the loop

Comment: How can i execute it?

Comment: you need to add a link of a company such as `www.mycompany.com...` which supplies e-mail sending as a transmitting service @Student_new

Comment: I mean you need an smtp server which is not in the scope of of programming, rather networking @Student_new . www.mycompany.com is just a dual link to symbolize such a server.

Comment: Dude, how are you?. Could you please take a look atthis: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335140/checking-if-the-price-of-modifiers-changed-oracle-11g ?