# Passing arguments inside procedure (message) not working - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I want to create a procedure but i am having trouble while passing the arguments inside a function

**This is my code:**

```
  select 'The concurrent '||program||' with request_id '||request_id||' ended with status '|| 
           status as message, request_id
    from
    (
       <the subquery>
      )
   where rn = 1
     and status in ('WARNING','ERROR','STAND BY');
```

It works just fine and everytime it runs i got this output:

```
|The concurrent Sales with request_id 987987678 ended with status WARNING|987987678
```

Now, i want to create a PROCEDURE using the query written above.. i want to send a mail with that information

This is what i got so far:

```
create or replace procedure pr_mail_me is

  v_email_test varchar2(100) := 'myemail@random.com';

cursor crs_request is

  select 'The concurrent '||program||' with request_id '||request_id||' ended with status '|| 
           status as message, request_id
    from
    (
       <the subquery>
      )
   where rn = 1
     and status in ('WARNING','ERROR','STAND BY');  

begin

  for c in crs_request
  loop
  begin


      utl_mail.send(sender => 'sendercompany@test.com',recipients => v_email ,subject => 'Concurrents' ,message => c.message);
   end;
  end loop;

end;
```

But this is NOT working. I want to receive the mail and that's why i am using this oracle function **utl_mail.send**

I need to receive this message inside the mail:

**The concurrent Sales with request_id 987987678 ended with status WARNING**

Also, how can i send this message to many other people? Can i use the same variable v_email_test

Comment: considering your SMTP server is setup correctly and you did not get any error when executing the proc, you might want to try this link - https://asktom.oracle.com/mobile/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=sending-mail-using-utl-mail  , their might be a grant missing.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I dont understand how to modifiy my code

Comment: you should have a communication table ,to hold e-mail addresses of each individual person, to be used to join with your current <the subquery>, and bring this column's value as the second argument of `utl_mail.send()` such as `utl_mail.send( ..., recipients => c.email, .... )`. In this case, you can get rid of `v_email_test` variable.

Comment: Hi @BarbarosÖzhan how would you do that? Also, my code is not working, this part does not seem correct: ,message => c.message

Comment: Dude, i tried but this is not working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59441036/error-while-passing-email-inside-utl-mail-send-oracle-11g-sql-06502-06512