# Error while passing email inside utl_mail.send (Oracle 11g - sql) 06502 - 06512

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am getting this error message:

```
Error at line 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error 
ORA-06512: in "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 654
ORA-06512: in "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 671
ORA-06512: in "APPS.PR_MAIL_ME", line 44
ORA-06512: in line 2
```

**This is my code, my cursor:**

```
  cursor email_detail is
  select email
    from
    (
       <the subquery>
      )
   where rn = 1
     and status in ('WARNING','ERROR','STAND BY');
```

**Then, i want to pass every single email inside utl_mail.send function using a LOOP**

```
begin

  for c in email_detail
  loop
    begin

      utl_mail.send(sender => 'send@mail.com',recipients => c.email ,subject => 'Concurrents' ,message => 'adasdas');
    end;  
  end loop;

end;
```

I've tried so many times to solve this but i failed, could you please help me to solve this?

Comment: You need to edit your question and post a [mcve] along with table definition and sample table data.

Comment: Hey dude, how are you? I am using a standard Oracle function called utl_mail.send but i do not understand how to pass the array :(

Answer (score 1):

In 11g, you will need to execute following commands before using `utl_mail` package:

```
@rdbms/admin/utlmail.sql
@rdbms/admin/prvtmail.plb
grant execute on utl_mail to <your_user_or_public>
```

Now, the important step is, you need to add the address and port of the e-mail server to the “`smtp_out_server`” initialization parameter. If you do not do this, you will receive a `“ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error”` error when you try to use the `UTL_MAIL` package.

See this oracle documentation for more details on [smtp_out_server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams230.htm#REFRN10241).

Cheers!!

Comment: Hey dude, thank you for replying!. If i use this function itself: utl_mail.send(sender => 'send@mail.com',recipients => 'myemail@mail.com' ,subject => 'Concurrents' ,message => 'adasdas'); the mail is sent properly. The problem appears when i use the cursor and the loop function, that's where the errors are shown. Is my code written properly?

Comment: Your code is proper but when you say it is working properly without cursor, is it from same database from where you are getting error with cursor? Is your smtp server and db conection is working properly?

Comment: Does my *'c.email'* inside utl_mail.send make any sense to you?.My cursor retrieves several rows and i want to put every single email from every single row inside the field 'recipients'. Do you get the idea?. Yeah, i am using a local database, an Oracle 11g database and if i use the function utl_mail.send(sender => 'send@mail.com',recipients => 'myemail@mail.com' ,subject => 'Concurrents' ,message => 'adasdas') and then click on execute, the mail is sent.

Comment: The problem is that i created a procedure within the cursor and the loop and for some reason it is not working in that way. Do you need the entire code?.I'm pretty lost :(

Comment: Dude, how do you set the address and port of the e-mail server to the “smtp_out_server"?

Comment: Also, how do you check if this step is already done?: @rdbms/admin/utlmail.sql
@rdbms/admin/prvtmail.plb

Comment: Simply check if UTL_MAIL package exists in sys schema? If yes then utlmail.sql execution step us performed. Check `show parameter smtp_out_server` to see if it is set. More info at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_mail.htm#BABFJJBD